# How to find and print intersections of n given circles in O(n*log(n)) time?

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, computational-geometry

I'm looking for an `O(n*logn)` algorithm to find and print the intersections of `n` given circles. Each circle is specified by its center and radius.

An O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm consists in checking if the distance between the centers is less than or equal to the sum of the radii (of the two circles being compared). However, I'm looking for a faster one!

A similar problem is intersection of line segments. I think even my problem can be solved using [line sweep algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm), but I am unable to figure out how to modify the event queue in-case of circles.

Please, take also care of the following corner case. The black points indicate the event points (*as per User Sneftel's solution below the intersection of circles marked by arrows won't be printed*)

[image: Please take care of this in your solution]

Comment: Are your circels sorted (e.g. by their center-x-coordinate)? Afaik they need to be sorted for *line sweep* to work efficiently
(Nevermind, your edit makes this clear)

Comment: No they are not, but as an initialization step, they may be sorted easily in O(nlogn) not affecting my desired bound of O(nlogn).

Comment: You mean intersection points of circle lines, right? Intersections of circles I would understand as areas. I find the drawing confusing. What are event points? Is this part of the question, or part of the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct solution I found based on a modification of User Sneftel's algorithm that wasn't working for all cases.

[image]

Fig 1 : Represent each circle by a bounded box.
Now to use the sweep line method, moving the sweep line parallel to y-axis we need TWO line segments to represent each circle's y-range as shown in figure 2.

[image]

Having done that the problem reduces to the following :

[image]

Here 2 line segments represent one circle.
Sweep line status can be maintained as any balanced dynamic data structure like AVL tree, Skip Lists, Red Black Trees having insertion/Update/Deletion/Retrieval time at-most O(logn).
The comparison function in this case will check if the two circles corresponding to the adjacent line segments intersect or not(In place of checking for line segments to intersect as in the original line sweep method for finding out line segment intersections). This can be done in O(1) time as constant amount of operations are required.
Number of Event Points : 4n (for n circles => 2n line segments => 4n end points)
Complexity = O(4nlog(4n)) = O(nlogn)

Comment: I don't see how your comparison function works. If the circles intersect, which is ranked higher? How would you construct the data structure with this function? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/23548473/6742968

Comment: Why bother with the second line segment? You can just store the highest line segment and additionally include the diameter of the circle to know big it is.

Answer (score 4):

The line sweep algorithm will simply add circles to a list when you encounter their left extrema (that is, `(x-r, y)`), and removed from the list when you encounter their right extrema. Right before you add a circle to the list, check it against the circles already in the list. So your event queue is basically the left and right extrema of all circles, sorted by x. (Note that you know all the events ahead of time, so it's not really a "queue" in the normal sense.)

This is also known as "sweep and prune".

Comment: Yeah, for the event queue I could use skip lists/ AVL trees / Red Black trees or any balanced DS for O(logn) time insert/delete!

Comment: Or a sorted array. As I say, you know all your events ahead of time. There's no insertion or deletion, just iteration.

Comment: I would definitely need a dynamic DS for finding out in each iteration which two circles become adjacent(to check for intersections in the sweep line status) rite?

Comment: You could use it for the active set of circles, true, and that might improve performance for circles which were not uniformly distributed. As a first pass, I would personally keep the active set as an array and do brute-force scan on the active circles. Which way is faster depends on how sparse your area is.

Comment: There will be only a single pass isn't it?
I think a single pass is sufficient. We could start with the circle having least value of (xc-r) ie the leftmost event point.
Add it to the sweep line status and update the sweep line status as the algorithm proceeds.

Comment: Question : Is it necessary to add the intersections of circles to the sweep line status in this case?

Comment: Yes, it'll just be one pass. And there's no reason to treat intersections as events, as long as you find *all* intersections of a circle when you add it to the active set (rather than just the closest one). A circle which starts below another circle will never end up above that circle later on.

Comment: The solution works for all cases but the one i posted in the edit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42126/discussion-between-sneftel-and-sahil-sareen)