# Computing circle intersections in O( (n+s) log n)

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, complexity-theory, intersection

I'm trying to figure out how to design an algorithm that can complete this task with a O((n+s) log n) complexity. s being the amount of intersections. I've tried searching on the internet, yet couldn't really find something.

Anyway, I realise having a good data structure is key here. I am using a Red Black Tree implementation in java: TreeMap. I also use the famous(?) sweep-line algorithm to help me deal with my problem.

Let me explain my setup first.

I have a Scheduler. This is a PriorityQueue with my circles ordered(ascending) based on their most left coordinate. `scheduler.next()` basically polls the PriorityQueue, returning the next most left circle.

```
public Circle next()
{ return this.pq.poll();    }
```

I also have an array with 4n event points in here. Granting every circle has 2 event points: most left x and most right x. The scheduler has a method sweepline() to get the next event point.

```
public Double sweepline()
{ return this.schedule[pointer++];    }
```

I also have a Status. The sweep-line status to be more precise. According to the theory, the status contains the circles that are eligible to be compared to each other. The point of having the sweep line in this whole story is that you're able to rule out a lot of candidates because they simply are not within the radius of current circles.

I implemented the Status with a `TreeMap<Double, Circle>`. Double being the `circle.getMostLeftCoord().`

This TreeMap guarantees O(log n) for inserting/removing/finding.

The algorithm itself is implemented like so:

```
Double sweepLine = scheduler.sweepline();
Circle c = null;
while (notDone){
    while((!scheduler.isEmpty()) && (c = scheduler.next()).getMostLeftCoord() >= sweepLine)
        status.add(c);


    /*
     * Delete the oldest circles that the sweepline has left behind
     */
    while(status.oldestCircle().getMostRightCoord() < sweepLine)
        status.deleteOldest();

    Circle otherCircle;
    for(Map.Entry<Double, Circle> entry: status.keys()){
        otherCircle = entry.getValue();
        if(!c.equals(otherCircle)){
            Intersection[] is = Solver.findIntersection(c, otherCircle);
            if(is != null)
                for(Intersection intersection: is)
                    intersections.add(intersection);
        }
    }

    sweepLine = scheduler.sweepline();
}
```

EDIT: `Solver.findIntersection(c, otherCircle);` returns max 2 intersection points. Overlapping circles are not considered to have any intersections.

The code of the SweepLineStatus

```
public class BetterSweepLineStatus {

TreeMap<Double, Circle> status = new TreeMap<Double, Circle>();

public void add(Circle c)
{ this.status.put(c.getMostLeftCoord(), c);     }

public void deleteOldest()
{ this.status.remove(status.firstKey());    }

public TreeMap<Double, Circle> circles()
{ return this.status;       }

public Set<Entry<Double, Circle>> keys()
{ return this.status.entrySet();    }

public Circle oldestCircle()
{ return this.status.get(this.status.firstKey());   }
```

I tested my program, and I clearly had O(n^2) complexity. 
What am I missing here? Any input you guys might be able to provide is more than welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "and I clearly had O(n^2) complexity" - this is impossible to tell from running a program, because otherwise you could solve the halting problem.

Comment: You want all intersection points of `n` circles in the plane in `O(n log n)` time, right? No constraints on the circles?

Comment: That's not proof. That's just experimental data.

Comment: @G.Bach Doesn't that proof I'm breaking the lower bound that is O(NlogN)?

Comment: @DanielBrückner no constraints on the circles afaik!

Comment: No, it doesn't, because you don't know what constants play into it, how hardware factors into it, etc. Also, you're not testing almost all instances. You may take it as a hint that your code might not have the complexity you desire, but it's definitely not proof for that.

Comment: @G.Bach It is not scientifically accurate but for telling whether a algorithm is `O(n log n)` or `O(n²)` or `O(2^n)` running a couple of test instances is good enough.

Comment: @DanielBrückner It's definitely not good enough, because that is a formal statement, and a formal statement requires formal proof. Running tests is good enough for telling you what kind of running times you can expect. It's not the right tool to tell complexities.

Comment: @G.Bach I am not after any formal proof, but if I design an O(nlogn) algorithm I at least expect it to exhibit its behaviour on a plot of every run I do. In this case, I was after a quick and dirty check, to know if I was doing it all right. The fact that all my plots indicate exponential growth for doubling N shows -to me- that this is definitely worse than O(N log N)

Comment: I was trying to come up with a solution using [power diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_diagram), which can be constructed in O(n log n), but don't know enough to conclude the solution is O((n+s) log n). It would be nice if for each circle, one needs only to check if it intersects its neighbor cells, then there are at most O(n) such checks because of a bound on the number of edges in the power diagram. However, it seems like a circle intersecting a neighbor cell may intersect neighbor cells of the neighbor, so I'm stuck. Maybe someone with more knowledge in power diagrams can help.

Comment: Another observation. As the accepted answer points out, the number of intersections in the worst case is O(n^2), so O((n+s)log n) is O(n^2 log n) in the worst case, which is worse than the O(n^2) method of comparing each circle pair. Unless there are some constraints on the circles that bound s, an O((n+s) log n) algorithm has no clear advantage over an O(n^2) one. Something better like O(n log n + s) as suggested by @mic_e is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not find all intersection points of `n` circles in the plane in `O(n log n)` time because every pair of circles can have up to two distinct intersection points and therefore `n` circles can have up to `n² - n` distinct intersection points and hence they can not be enumerated in `O(n log n)` time.

One way to obtain the maximum number of `n² - n` intersection points is to place the centers of `n` circles of equal radius `r` at mutually different points of a line of length `l < 2r`.

[image: Intersecting circles]

Comment: See mcdowella's answer for intuition on how to arrange the circles.

Comment: The question is still valid, but shuld be re-formulated: Computing circle-intersections in O(nlogn + k), where n is the number of circles, and k is the number of intersections.

Answer (score 4):

N circles with the same centre and radius will have N(N-1)/2 pairs of intersecting circles, while by using large enough circles so that their boundaries are almost straight lines you can draw a grid with N/2 lines intersecting each of N/2 lines, which is again N^2. I would look and see how many entries are typically present in your map when you add a new circle.

You might try using bounding squares for your circles and keeping an index on the pending squares so that you can find only squares which have y co-ordinates that intersect your query square (assuming that the sweep line is parallel to the y axis). This would mean that - if your data was friendly, you could hold a lot of pending squares and only check a few of them for possible intersections of the circles within the squares. Data unfriendly enough to cause real N^2 intersections is always going to be a problem.

Comment: I think arranging the circles can be done for any restrictions on the radius of the circles since the suggested positioning should "scale".

Comment: @GBach - I think you're right. It's not really a question of the size of the circles as of the combination of size and relative positions. I just found it convenient to think of standing beside a circle so large in comparison to me that all I could see looked like a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

How large are the circles compared to the entire area? If the ratio is small enough I would consider putting them into buckets of some sort. It'll make the complexity a little more complicated than `O(n log n)` but should be faster.